# Specialization and template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I've the following:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class C, class T, class A >
class TTCTest
{
public:
        TTCTest(C<T, A> parameter) { /* ... some stuff... */ }
        C<T, A> _collection;
};
```

I want to ensure that the template is only instantiated where the T and A classes are of a specific type (path and allocator respectively).

For example:

```
...
list<path, allocator<path> > list1;
list<int, allocator<int> > list2;

TTCTest<list> testvar(list1); // ...should work
TTCTest<list> testvar(list2); // ...should not work
...
```

Is this possible and what is the syntax?

Regards,
Col

Comment: if C and T always have to be path and allocator, why should they be template parameters?

Comment: I guess I'm not good at this question asking! :-)  I would like to specialize the template for those cases.

Comment: Then forward declare the general case, and provide a class body only for that particular partial specialization.

Comment: Hi Ben - I'm unsure of the syntax for doing so.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: the answer depends on whether you need one class to work with your template (then partial specialization can be the solution) or you have a set of classes for which you want to have the same implementation (then constraining template instantiation can be a solution).

Comment: Hi Gene - it is the former case I am interested in.

Comment: Essentially - I am wanting to be able to pass in any collection but specialize for when the T (type) and A (allocator) of the given collection are specific types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with partial specialisation, where you fail to provide an implementation for the non-specialised case.
For example:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class C, class T, class A >
class TTCTest;

template <template <typename, typename> class C>
class TTCTest<C, path, allocator<path> >
{
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create trait class to constraint instantiations. For example, limit your TTCTest construction only to `path` type:

```
template<class T, class A> class path {};
template<class T, class A> class not_path {};

template<class T> class allocation {};

template<class T>
struct Testable;

template<class T, class A>
struct Testable<path<T,A> > {};

template <template <typename, typename> class C, 
class T, class A >
class TTCTest
{
public:
        TTCTest(C<T, A> parameter, Testable<C<T,A> > = Testable<C<T,A> >());
        C<T, A> _collection;
};

void foo()
{
   path<int, allocation<int> > p;
   TTCTest<path, int, allocation<int> > t(p); // compiles

   not_path<int, allocation<int> > np;
   TTCTest<not_path, int, allocation<int> > t1(np); // fails
}
```

Edit:
Since you indicated later that all you might need is partial specialization, in which case it would look like this:

```
template <class T, class A >
class TTCTest<path, T, A>
{
public:
        TTCTest(path<T, A> parameter);
        path<T, A> _collection;
};
```