# Problem with partial template specialization with CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I can't figure out how to partially specialize a base class that uses the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP). The specialty of this CRTP is that the derived class itself is a class template. Here's what I try:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

template<class T> class Word;

template<class T, template<class> class C>
class BaseView
{
public:
  BaseView() { cout << "normal BaseView" << endl; }
};


#if 0
template<class T, template<class> class C >
class BaseView<Word<T> , C<Word<T> > >
{
public:
  BaseView() { cout << "BaseView specialized on Word" << endl; }
};
#endif


template<class T> class A: public BaseView<T,A>
{
public:
  A():BaseView<T,A>() {}
};





int main()
{
  A<A<Word<int> > > a0;
  A<Word<int> > a1;
}
```

I'd like the construction of the second object (a1) to use the (partially) specialized base class (the one that's ifdef'd out in the code above).

GCC++ v12 tells me that for the 2nd argument in the template parameter list it expected a class template, got ‘C<Word >. Which makes sense, but I don't know how to change the code to make it work.

Comment: No compiler error here: https://godbolt.org/z/oqG7fK4v6 You may need to fully reproduce the error message you are seeing rather than paraphrasing it.

Comment: @user4581301: In your link, you kept `#if 0`. Changing it to `#if 1` reproduces the OP's error.

Comment: @tbxfreeware Never occurs to me that some folk post a "working" version of their example code. Seems kind of counter-productive.

Comment: Why can't you use `template<class T, template<class> class C> class BaseView<Word<T>, C>`?

Comment: Do you really need to specialize on `C`? I see no such need from your code. If you don't need to specialize on `C`, just need to specialize on `T`, you should just define your `BaseView` as `BaseView<T>`. The fact that `T` may be an instance of a template is irrelavent and you can always do `template<class T> class A: public BaseView<A<T>>` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specialize a class template with a template template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426292/how-to-specialize-a-class-template-with-a-template-template-parameter)

Comment: @WeijunZhou *"I see no such need from your code."* -- That is a consequence of appropriately simplifying to a [mre]. We don't need to see how the template parameter will be used when the question is about how to specify the template arguments. Please do not encourage people to make their example code more complex than is necessary to demonstrate the question.

Comment: @JaMiT I have used CRTP where the base class is specialized for the same pattern (for this example, it is `Word<T>`), and where the child class is a template itself, and `BaseView<T>` does the job quite well, so basically I'm wondering maybe OP doesn't really need the template parameter `C` at all. I should have made it clear that I can see such need neither from the code nor the way the question is worded. Of course if the question text already addresses the need, then the MCVE does not need to show it. Finally I agree that if `C` is actually needed, the comment by Evg is the way to go.

Comment: @Evg, yes, I can use that. I completely missed that. I suppose I was misled by the fact that in my use cases, 'C' is always templated on the same 'Word<T>"

Comment: @WeijunZhou the 'BaseView' template has methods that return a type of 'T' and it inspects the derived class. So, I believe that both 'T' and 'C' are necessary.

Comment: Acutally you can still figure out the type of `T` and inspect the derived class with only a template parameter, so `C` is not strictly necessary unless you need to specialize it. However, that would make things unnecessarily complex and maybe in this case using two type parameters is likely the better and more natural option. Thank you for your clarification still.